# How to get class type information from generics?

Tags: java, generics

I have a problem, I need to resolve type of class which replaced the generic type parameter. Here is the code:

```
public class EnumSetPlay {

    private enum SomeEnum {ONE, TWO}

    private static class Test<E extends Enum> {
        private Class<E> clazz = (Class<E>) GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument(getClass(), Test.class);;

        public void test() {
            for (E element : EnumSet.allOf(clazz))
                System.out.println(element);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Test<SomeEnum>().test();
    }
}
```

I need to get class type **SomeEnum**.
I trying to use spring GenericTypeResolver class, but I have next error:

```
error: incompatible types
required: E
found:    Object
where E is a type-variable:
E extends Enum declared in class Test
```

Comment: it is usually better to type with `<E extends Enum<E>>`

Comment: I repaire that but now I have NullPointerException, because the clazz is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible due to *type erasure*, which removes the type information. Some links:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html
- [Java generics - type erasure - when and what happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)
- http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html

Comment: Indeed.  This is just _not possible._

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    public class EnumSetPlay {

    private enum SomeEnum {
        ONE, TWO
    }

    private static class Test<E extends Enum<E>> {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        private Class<E> clazz = (Class<E>) GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument(getClass(), Test.class); ;

        public void test() {
            for (E element : EnumSet.allOf(clazz))
                System.out.println(element);
        }
    }

    private static class DummyTest extends Test<SomeEnum> {
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new DummyTest().test();
    }

}
```

Comment: this is different than what is asked

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is simply not possible because of type-erasure as explained in other answers. If you to achieve what you are trying to do, the only solution is to pass the class as a parameter of the constructor:

```
public class EnumSetPlay {

    private enum SomeEnum {ONE, TWO}

    private static class Test<E extends Enum<E>> {
        private Class<E> clazz ;

        public Test(Class<E> clazz) {
            this.clazz = clazz;
        }

        public void test() {
            for (E element : EnumSet.allOf(clazz))
                System.out.println(element);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Test<SomeEnum>().test();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have this solution, but it seems like unnecessary duplication, so I wanted to make it simplier.